# Having more than one auth in rails endpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm reading through some code that I see two things that I had questions about:

1. There is a controller endpoint in a Rails app that uses two kinds of auth: basic and Jwt. Are both necessary or can I remove one?
2. The Jwt token is being put in a header called `JwtAuthorization` before hitting the endpoint. This seems non-standard as the common header is called `Authorization`. Is this bad? Why or why not? Why do standards have to be abided by?

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends. Basic auth and JWT are two totally different methods of authentication. You need to check the rest of the code-base and see if one of the two authentication methods is redundant. I guess you've looked into what [Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) authentication and [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/) is. As you can see, you *can* use both.
2. It's not necessarily bad. Of course, it's always better to follow standards. It's not just for programs, but for humans as well. Almost everyone expects to find authorization information in the `Authorization` header. Note though that if your app is being proxied, some proxies might strip away non-standard headers. Additionally, it is common to name custom headers starting with an "X", like `X-Custom-Header`.

A general note on standards. You don't *have* to adhere to them. Just look at browsers. Every browser implements features differently. Some follow the standard spec, some don't. What might work for one might not work for another. If you're planning to open your app to the public, it's better to conform to standards. If not, then it's up to you and your team.

Comment: So this app DOES follow standards. Given that... is it possibly to jam two tokens inside the Authorization header for a rails app that's receiving it? I guess it is right?

Comment: Exactly. You can do anything you want, as long as there is a "contract" between the server and the client. If you, as the server developer, tell me, the client, that you expect every request to have a certain header and its value in a specific format, then it is my "duty" as the client to respect the contract. That's what protocols are. Standard or non-standard is a decision that's governed by a lot of factors and limitations.